# Why does my QGestureRecognizer not receive Touch Events?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, qt5.2

*Context: I'm trying to create a fader-like widget that can have multiple instances in the same view, each of which can be controlled simultaneously by different fingers.*

I want to use Qt's [gesture recognition system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/gestures-overview.html), but I also need some functionality above and beyond the standard `Qt::PanGesture`. To this end, I've subclassed both `QGesture` and `QGestureRecognizer`. In `FooGestureRecognizer::recognize(...)`, I'm currently intercepting both `QMouseEvent`s and `QTouchEvent`s (for the time being, at least).

On Windows I only receive `QMouseEvent`s - I handle them and everything works as expected (though obviously I don't have to deal with the multitouch problem when my input is from a physical mouse). The events I receive (in order):

- `QEvent::MouseButtonPress`
- A string of `QEvent::MouseMove`s
- `QEvent::MouseButtonRelease`

On Android, I receive a strange mix of `QMouseEvent`s and `QTouchEvent`s (in order):

- `QEvent::TouchBegin`
- `QEvent::MouseButtonPress`
- `QEvent::MouseMove` (with no actual change in position)
- Another `QEvent::MouseButtonPress` (not sure why I needed another one)
- My actual string of `QEvent::MouseMove`s, as expected
- `QEvent::MouseButtonRelease`

The global attribute [`Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qt.html#ApplicationAttribute-enum) is `true` by default. Turning it off changes the events I receive to:

- `QEvent::TouchBegin`

...nothing else.

Here's a precursor question then: **What can I do inside `QGestureRecognizer::recognize()` to tell Qt that I'm handling the `QEvent::TouchBegin`, and that it doesn't need to synthesize a `QEvent::MouseButtonPress` for me?** `event->accept()` doesn't appear to make any difference.

The actual question: **If (as it appears) Qt is synthesizing `MouseEvent`s from `TouchEvent`s, why do I see I see `QEvent::MouseMove` and `QEvent::MouseButtonRelease` but not `QEvent::TouchUpdate` or `QEvent::TouchRelease`?**

Code is available, but in the interests of conciseness I've not included it here. Please ask if needed.

Answer (score 4):

From the [`QTouchEvent` docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtouchevent.html#event-handling):

> The QEvent::TouchUpdate and QEvent::TouchEnd events are sent to the widget or item that accepted the QEvent::TouchBegin event. If the QEvent::TouchBegin event is not accepted and not filtered by an event filter, then no further touch events are sent until the next QEvent::TouchBegin.

The root of this problem is that `QGestureRecognizer` does not accept the initial `TouchBegin`, and hence we don't receive any further touch events. I got around this by:

1. Creating a thin event filter `QObject` owned by my `QGestureRecognizer`.

Containing the following code:

```
bool FooGestureRecognizer::FooEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *Object, QEvent *Event)
{
  if(Event->type() == QEvent::TouchBegin)
  {
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
    return QObject::eventFilter(Object, Event);
  }
}
```

2. Installing my event filter AND calling `setAttribute(Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents)` on every valid* `Target` that comes through `FooGestureRecognizer::create()`.

Returning `true` from `eventFilter` tells Qt that my fader is interested in receiving further touch events, and these touch events are delivered as expected to the gesture recognizer.

This solution feels like a hack, and one that might not be necessary in future versions of Qt, so I'm going to keep an eye on this code.

*Notes:*

- *During the construction of a `QGestureRecognizer`, `create()` is called with a null `Target` (expecting a dummy `QGesture` to be returned). Watch out for this if you're installing event filters on all `Target`s.*
- *My application needs to handle desktop mouse events in one way, and multi-finger touch events in another, so I've disabled `Qt::AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents`. Keeping this enabled may lead to other considerations (e.g. I'm not sure if you'd need to `return true` for all touch events in `eventFilter`, so as to avoid them being duplicated as synthesised mouse events).*